# Was StartPosition added to IndexOf function in JS on a later stage?

Tags: javascript, indexof

We have a discussion in the office and I am not able to find the answer.

According to my colleage `indexOf` in JS is always finding only the first match, from the beginning of the string.

But since there is the `startPosition` parameter this is no longer true.

So my question is - is it possible, that the StartPosition parameter was presented in JS on a later stage?

Comment: `But since there is the StartPosition parameter this is no longer true`. Wrong. It still returns the first match from the start position provided.

Comment: Exactly, but not from the 0 char!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very [first edition of ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) lists the method with this signature in section 15.5.4.6:

```
String.prototype.indexOf(searchString, position)
```

So no, it's always been there.

Comment: Link: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf (see 15.5.4.6)

Comment: Thanks for sharing!